# Truffle build dont find _mint and _burn -DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier. Did you mean "mint"? _mint(to, amount);

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

after some trouble with remix I'm back at a npm/truffle/ganache setup...

The reason why I tried out remix was:

```
DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier. Did you mean "mint"?
        _mint(to, amount);
```

And what can I say... stuck at the same place:

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.8.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";


contract Testyis IERC20, Ownable {
   using SafeMath for uint256;
   using SafeMath for uint8;
   
   address _owner;
   
   
...
   

constructor () public {
    _owner = address(msg.sender);
    _decimals = 18;

...
    
    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public {
        require((pre == msg.sender), "Caller is not a minter");
        _mint(to, amount);
    }

    function burn(address from, uint256 amount) public {
        require((pre == msg.sender), "Caller is not a burner");
        _burn(from, amount);
    }
}
```

"pre" is in this case another contract. When I use remix and import ERC20Detailed with a "normal" github path, then it works. Okay the other contract cant mint or burn, but at least I can do it and also set the pre address.

Hope someone can help :)

Comment: `IERC20` does not define function `_mint`.

Comment: Cant use ERC20 need to override ... even when it should supported I cant ....

Answer (score 1):

Function `_mint` is not declared in interface `IERC20`.

However, it is implemented as an `internal` function in contract `ERC20`.

So just change `contract Test is IERC20` to `contract Test is ERC20`.

By the way, even if function `_mint` **was** declared in interface `IERC20`, your code still wouldn't compile because you'd need to implement that function in the contract which inherits that interface.

Comment: Can't override function anymore if I use ERC20

Even when I use the latest openzeppelin/contracts ```"dependencies": {
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^3.3.0",
    "truffle": "^5.1.57",
    "zeppelin-solidity": "^1.12.0"
  },```